# Current transformer not returning expected result in rectifier output

Tags: current, transformer, current-measurement

I have reading about current transformer to measure current of A/C loads and I don't know if I understood it because the simulation that I made didn't worked properly.

So, I read about it here:

https://resources.altium.com/p/current-transformers-how-project

and I used this diagram:

[image]

and the replication of it resulted on this:

[image]

PS:

1st - I misunderstood how this simulator worked and I wasn't configuring the transformer properly. Now I Am:

[image]

2nd - I removed the second diode as suggested.

So:

- The green lines are the voltage and the yellow ones are the current.
- The TC transformer is with ratio as 1A in load results in 1mA in the burden resistor. (I think this is 1:1000?)
- The op-amp are ideal and feed with symmetrical source of 15V.
- The diode is ideal.

[Link for simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEDoE4DMAWATKhl0A2AdnVW0gA4RN1kb0AoAFXE0xGwUM80jY6Dw8TrEJ5IYMLUolKFHgFoYcBcVqRUqTKTxSoaLYwBuIQh2kdznblHBn+2Pnf4wEjAE69+l7zZ4+cIwA5pyU1JjU2OFmHJCefr5O-JSuwvCMACY0cLE0kXnYIJkApgBmAIYArgA2AC6MAO5+qWHUrfHN0e2OMWCErk351Nbs1P2DXt3gA8MzaWDw8RU0qDytJEWtqJz8ihTpSwYU6LhSxGuSlOQQMCe4xNjElOjoj6lgSItLQ2N5mGs8p1VjxAQCeGBiAEEuDwFCQZwnHZ8EFQrDsEj0Y8oDDAZCeJs4QFDsDCRtsficV4yfxiAgtgtUvEAMYgOkMtn0+Z2MAlRTEAziTD4eSET7C6LEMAhTlFCayok45rskCtcIpQahZL+PzTZZtf65aw7T4gRSm75HO6QfBSMWPKROBDUQI-Ly+XzWXz8fCMAAenKsO3CO2xFg4ACUAKIAYWYAEkAGLxqMRgA6AGcAPIAVWYAAU8-7VRApCbsBCMTReCAagB7CqZIZJWzWLjQuv2ayOSCROinfiEaBxTj2OgAQQA9DHMwBlXMRmNRxidordsIkOLD56EU7PJ7qLjYW6wOCl0dFOgAIRzEYAIlGAHKZ6Oz+Oz5hZiMr3ZAjd08BhwxJ5IioMB0HkVIAlPSR7AgaM4yTFN02zPNC2YH9sDoddohIOgVDPGhoAuMBcE0Z5MHAi4ogvfsQAAGSzcc70zGNb2jR8MKAA)

Bu I am probably missing something because the article created this circuit in real life and it worked just fine, with 4.76766A in the load they got 4.429V RMS in the rectifier output (7% off).

But I tried to reproduce this using a load of 50ohms with source of 240V resulting in a current of 4.8A, and I was expecting the value of the rectifier output to be 4.8V RMS but I am getting 1.01V RMS. That is not right. What could I have missed recreating this circuit diagram?

Comment: What is the turns ratio of your current transformer?  Not sure what this means: "But I used a load of 50ohms with source of 240V resulting in a current of 4.8V".  You have 4.8A in the burden resistor? That's basically a space heater.

Comment: @JohnD 1A in primary (load) will return 1mA in the secondary (output to rectifier input).

Comment: But the burden resistor goes on the secondary side of the CT, looks like you have it in the primary?  You want to put a load in series with the CT and the AC source, and the burden resistor on the secondary.

Comment: Your CT primary should be in SERIES with your 50 Ohm load resistor. You also need to define the Pri/sec turns ratio. What you show has the CT in parallel with the load ....definitely wrong.

Comment: Sorry, was thinking that the 50 ohms was the burden resistor, it's supposed to be the load, but my (and @JackCreasey's) comment still applies, put the load in series with the CT and the source.

Comment: @JackCreasey Yep, my horrible mistake, fixed the question diagram.

Comment: What kind of op-amp model are you using?  What are the supply rails (if the model has supplies)?

Comment: @JohnD those are op-amp with symmetric supply of 15V and 100k gain.

Comment: I don't see any rectification going on, maybe check your diode model?  I'd just go stage by stage: Does the CT output look like you expect?  Is the first op-amp rectification stage working?  etc.  BTW your 1K burden resistor looks like a pretty large value.

Comment: @JohnD There are two diodes shown in the schematic, but you only need the first one .....and though I do agree that 1k seems high for a burden value, the fact that the turns ration is not shown in the question makes it impossible to provide concise answers.

Comment: @JohnD I was testing the circuit, the burden is supposed to be 100ohms. I fixed the question.

Comment: @JackCreasey I tried to update the question with more information, I was doing a mistake with the transformer, can you check if its okay now? I'm not familiar with transformers.